# Using a single instantation throughout an entire project

Tags: c#, oop, singleton

I have a pretty basic question, but a question nonetheless.

In my Game class

```
public Game()
{
  PopulateGameTitles();
  PopulateGameReleaseDates();
}
```

I want to ensure that this Object is only ever created once throughout my project. So basically, creating a 
    new Game() won't instantiate a new one but reference the lone instantiation.

I suspect I would make this a Singleton but I am curious as to how to implement this when I have calculations in a base constructor.

Comment: Have you thought about making it `static`?

Comment: I would have to re-write all of the methods/properties to reflect that, then. Is this the only way?

Comment: certainly not the only way, I just wanted to make sure that you had at least considered it.

Comment: So yeah, I can't go the static route, at least, I don't think so. I would like to explore other ways.

Comment: Amazingly, your question is already answered in the tags you chose for this question: use the Singleton pattern

Comment: Btw, a singleton is similar to a static class, so either way you're going to have to do some redesigning of your class.

Comment: Something like private static Game gameInstance = null; public static Game GameInstance { get return gameInstance ?? (gameInstance = new Game()); Can I have this base contructor below?

Answer (score 0):

The way you've described the problem, you definitely want a singleton. You won't be using `new Game()` to reach it, though. Jon Skeet has an excellent [article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) on singletons, and how to implement them. 
 
I would, however, encourage you to consider other options in organizing you program. Singletons are dangerous because they represent shared state, where parts of your program very far apart can affect each other unintentionally by interacting with this singleton. You may want to figure out if you really need this to be shared everywhere, or if there may be another way to distribute this data through your program.